# Find MVVM Property Name of TextBox On Runtime based On TextBox Name in Wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to Find TextBox MVVM Property name whom TextBox bind with on Runtime .

```
<TextBox Name="txtCityName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding CityName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="40" Width="200"/>

<TextBox Name="CountryName"   Text="None"   Height="40" Width="200" Margin="159,184,158,95"/>
```

Above is My Two TextBox. Both Bind With Property.
In Code Behind When I run My Wpf Application.

I put all the TextBox name into one file. Once File Loaded and give me 
TextBox Name i want to get the  MVVM Property Name On Run Time

Comment: The Question not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `TextBox` is data-bound using the `GetBindingExpression` method:

```
var be = txtCityName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
if(be != null && be.ParentBinding != null)
{
    string sourceProperty = be.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . Great Work. You save my Time